# Update parameter on bpy.context.active_pose_bone changed

Tags: scripting

I would like to update a custom scene parameter when selecting between different pose bones.  Blender does not allow value to be updated on draw() method.  Though I might need to add a method to a handler but I can see any for active_pose_bone or selection changed.

Does anyone know how to update a parameter on selection event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Getter (Setter) on a property**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html)

Small example, added `active_pose_bone_length` property to the scene.  Reports the length of the active pose bone or zero if none.  (AFAIK Blender bones cannot have zero length)

This way you are computing your property based on the selection, rather than checking selection change.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import FloatProperty
from bpy.types import Scene

def get(self):
    pb = bpy.context.active_pose_bone
    return pb.length if pb else 0


Scene.active_pose_bone_length = FloatProperty(get=get)
```

alternatively could make this a context property

```
import bpy

def get(self):
    pb = self.active_pose_bone
    return pb.length if pb else 0


bpy.types.Context.active_pose_bone_length = property(get)
```

Comment: Thank you the getter setter is working I just had to drop the ', context' part following this page: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html

Comment: Cheers, mixed update props with getter. Busted for not checking code.  Worth mentioning can do `bpy.types.Context.foo = property(get)` also